# vlc http stream with android

Tags: android, vlc, http-streaming

I compiled vlc for android with version 1.8 and I found a official demo with link:
https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample .It's works fine with localVideo. I try to play a http stream, so I change the code below:

```
 // Create LibVLC
// TODO: make this more robust, and sync with audio demo
ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
//options.add("--subsdec-encoding <encoding>");
options.add("--aout=opensles");
options.add("--audio-time-stretch"); // time stretching
options.add("-vvv"); // verbosity
libvlc = new LibVLC(options);
libvlc.setOnHardwareAccelerationError(this);
holder.setKeepScreenOn(true);

// Create media player
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libvlc);
mMediaPlayer.setEventListener(mPlayerListener);

// Set up video output
final IVLCVout vout = mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
vout.setVideoView(mSurface);
//vout.setSubtitlesView(mSurfaceSubtitles);
 vout.addCallback(this);
 vout.attachViews();

//Media m = new Media(libvlc, media);
 Uri uri =  Uri.parse(httpAddress);
  Media m = new Media(libvlc,  uri);
  mMediaPlayer.setMedia(m);
  mMediaPlayer.play();
```

It's works fine on samsung,android 4.1.2. But it's crash with mi4 mobile. with start, it's has 2 seconds sound without image, then it's crash,just like ANR but stay the black screen for ever.
here is the logcat:

```
core video output: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 953 ms)
core vout display: Failed to change zoom
android_window vout display: change source crop/aspect
core video output: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 1156 ms)
core vout display: auto hiding mouse cursor
core audio output: playback too late (66254): up-sampling
core video output: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 1155 ms)
core video output: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 1153 ms)
[OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] ERROR(0x80001009)
Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001009, internalError -2147483648)
mediacodec decoder: Exception in MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer
mediacodec decoder: dequeue_out failed
mediacodec decoder: OutThread stopped
threadid=16: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
Error with hardware acceleration
```

[more log info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAH1H.png)
where can i find a httpstream demo with vlc complied 1.8?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok,when i close hardware acceleration,it's works fine.I use code    media.setHWDecoderEnabled(false, false);

Answer (score 1):

Issue of this nature are due to HardwareDecoder on board, [this awesome page](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#samples) compiles up all the Decoding capability on Android.

**The MediaCodec class first became available in Android 4.1 (API 16).**

**In Android 4.3 (API 18), MediaCodec was expanded to include a way to provide input through a Surface (via the createInputSurface method).**

Even though Android Introduced MediaCodec in a big way on 4.3, not all vendors support them, need to have intelligent Player/Decoder to switch to Software Decoding.

`LibVLC` does it intelligently but need to manage it through `LibVLC Options`.